# How to make a landscape table fill the whole width?

Tags: tables, margins, landscape

It seems that neither `\textwidth` nor `\textheight` can force the table to fill the whole width.

```
\documentclass[dvips]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=20mm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{longtable,array}

\begin{document}
\chapter{One}
\lipsum[1]
\section{One One}
\lipsum[2]

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}{|m{0.4\textheight-2\tabcolsep-1.5\fboxrule}|m{0.6\textheight-2\tabcolsep-1.5\fboxrule}|}
\hline
a & b\\\hline
c & d\\\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\pagestyle{plain}

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

---

**EDIT 1:**

I made a correction in the column width, i.e., changing `2\fboxrule` to `1.5\fboxrule`. The former calculation is wrong because the rule between 2 columns should NOT be calculated twice. I slipped a little here.

And I got an output as follows:

[image]

---

**EDIT 2: It's my real scenario (as opposed to the minimal code)**

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames,rgb,dvips]{book}

\usepackage[a4paper,margin=20mm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{lscape}

\newcounter{No}
\renewcommand{\theNo}{\stepcounter{No}\arabic{No}}
\newenvironment{MyTable}[4]%
{%
    \newcolumntype{A}[1]%
    {%
        >{%
            \begin{minipage}%
                {%
                    ##1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth%
                }%
                \vspace{\tabcolsep}%
         }%
         c%
        <{\vspace{\tabcolsep}\end{minipage}}%
    }%
    \setcounter{No}{0}%comment out this if you want to continuous numbering for all tables.
    \begin{longtable}%
    {%
            |>{\scriptsize\centering\theNo}A{#1}<{}%
            |>{}A{#2}<{\centering\input{\jobname.tmp}}%
            |>{\centering\lstinputlisting{\jobname.tmp}}A{#3}<{}%
            |>{\scriptsize\arraybackslash}A{#4}<{}%
            |%
    }%
    \hline\ignorespaces%
}%
{%
    \end{longtable}%
}

\newcommand{\Comment}[1]{& & & #1\\\hline}


\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{%
language={PSTricks},
basicstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize,%
keywordstyle=\color{blue}%,
%backgroundcolor=\color{yellow!30}%
}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}


\def\MyRow{%        
        \VerbatimEnvironment%
        \begin{VerbatimOut}{\jobname.tmp}%
}

\def\endMyRow{%
        \end{VerbatimOut}%      
}



\usepackage{pstricks,pst-node}
\newpsstyle{gridstyle}{%
gridwidth=0.4pt,%default: 0.8pt
gridcolor=Red!20,%default: black
griddots=0,%default: 0 
%
gridlabels=3pt,%default: 10pt
gridlabelcolor=Blue,%default: black
%
subgriddiv=5,%default: 5
subgridwidth=0.2pt,%default: 0.4pt
subgridcolor=Green!20,%default: gray
subgriddots=0%default: 0
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction to PSTricks}
\lipsum[1]

\section{At a glance galleries}
\lipsum[1-5]

%Landscape starts here.
%\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{landscape}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{MyTable}{0.05}{.25}{0.4}{0.3}%
%=============
\begin{MyRow}
\pspicture*[showgrid](4,4)
\pnode(1,1){A}
\pnode(3,3){B}
\ncline{A}{B}
\endpspicture
\end{MyRow}
\Comment{\lipsum[1]}
%=============
\begin{MyRow}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](4,3)
\psframe*[linecolor=red!30](3,2)
\end{pspicture}
\end{MyRow}
\Comment{\lipsum[2]}
%=============
\begin{MyRow}
\pspicture[showgrid](4,3)
\psframe*[linecolor=green!30](3,2)
\endpspicture
\end{MyRow}
\Comment{\lipsum[3]}
%=============
\begin{MyRow}
\pspicture[showgrid](4,3)
\psframe*[linecolor=yellow!30](3,2)
\endpspicture
\end{MyRow}
\Comment{\lipsum[4]}
%=============
\begin{MyRow}
\pspicture[showgrid](4,3)
\psframe*[linecolor=Maroon!30](3,2)
\endpspicture
\end{MyRow}
\Comment{\lipsum[5]}
%=============
\end{MyTable}
%Landscape stops here.
\end{landscape}
%\pagestyle{plain}

\section{Node}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, `\arrayrulewidth` does not work.

---

**EDIT 3:**

`dvips` has been added for both code snippets above. The `\arrayrulewidth` still cannot work the way we want.

Comment: do you run latex or pdflatex?

Comment: @Herbert, I always use latex.exe because I use PSTricks package.

Comment: then use _always_ the `dvips` option in the document header to tell geometry how it should pass the page dimensions to the program `dvips` (see my header)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my solution

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames,rgb,dvips]{book}

\usepackage[a4paper,margin=20mm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\newcounter{No}
\renewcommand{\theNo}{\stepcounter{No}\arabic{No}}
\newcolumntype{A}[1]{%
  >{\vspace*{\medskipamount}\Centering}
  p{#1\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth}
  <{\smallskip}}
\newenvironment{MyTable}[4]%
  {\setcounter{No}{0}%comment out this if you want to continuous numbering for all tables.
   \begin{longtable}{%
            |>{\scriptsize\theNo}A{#1}<{}%
            |>{}l<{\minipage[t]{#2\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth}
                   \vspace{0pt}\input{\jobname.tmp}\endminipage}%
            |>{\Centering\lstinputlisting{\jobname.tmp}}A{#3}<{}%
            |>{\scriptsize\arraybackslash}A{#4}<{}%
            |%
    }%
    \hline\ignorespaces%
}%
{%
    \end{longtable}%
}

\newcommand{\Comment}[1]{& & & #1\\\hline}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{%
language={PSTricks},
basicstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize,%
keywordstyle=\color{blue}%,
%backgroundcolor=\color{yellow!30}%
}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\def\MyRow{%        
        \VerbatimEnvironment%
        \begin{VerbatimOut}{\jobname.tmp}}

\def\endMyRow{\end{VerbatimOut}}

\usepackage{pstricks,pst-node}
\newpsstyle{gridstyle}{%
gridwidth=0.4pt,%default: 0.8pt
gridcolor=Red!20,%default: black
griddots=0,%default: 0 
%
gridlabels=3pt,%default: 10pt
gridlabelcolor=Blue,%default: black
%
subgriddiv=5,%default: 5
subgridwidth=0.2pt,%default: 0.4pt
subgridcolor=Green!20,%default: gray
subgriddots=0%default: 0
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction to PSTricks}
\lipsum[1]

\section{At a glance galleries}
\lipsum[1-5]

%Landscape starts here.
%\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{landscape}
\noindent
\rule{\linewidth}{4pt}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{MyTable}{0.05}{.25}{0.4}{0.3}%
%=============
\begin{MyRow}
\pspicture[showgrid](4,4)
\pnode(1,1){A}
\pnode(3,3){B}
\ncline{A}{B}
\endpspicture
\end{MyRow}
\Comment{\lipsum[1]}
%=============
\begin{MyRow}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](4,3)
\psframe*[linecolor=red!30](3,2)
\end{pspicture}
\end{MyRow}
\Comment{\lipsum[2]}
%=============
\begin{MyRow}
\pspicture[showgrid](4,3)
\psframe*[linecolor=green!30](3,2)
\endpspicture
\end{MyRow}
\Comment{\lipsum[3]}
%=============
\begin{MyRow}
\pspicture[showgrid](4,3)
\psframe*[linecolor=yellow!30](3,2)
\endpspicture
\end{MyRow}
\Comment{\lipsum[4]}
%=============
\begin{MyRow}
\pspicture[showgrid](4,3)
\psframe*[linecolor=Maroon!30](3,2)
\endpspicture
\end{MyRow}
\Comment{\lipsum[5]}
%=============
\end{MyTable}
%Landscape stops here.
\end{landscape}
%\pagestyle{plain}

\section{Node}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Herbert, I have to submit my real scenario because the table I used is very tricky (there is a nested minipage inside each cell). Please kindly to see again my edit 2 above.

Comment: @Herbert, which one is the correct one: `2\arrayrulewidth` or `1.5\arrayrulewidth` ?

Comment: depends to what you want to describe. For a minipage inside a cell -2, for a cell in a tabular header it is one time 2 and all the other 1. For n cells you have n+1 lines. However, for a minipage inside _one_ cell you can choose `\columnwidth`, then it is correct.

Comment: @Herbert, thanks for the answer above. Anyway, why did you pull out the `\newcolumntype`? In my book, I deliberately put it inside such that I can use the same name for creating other table, for example, called `MyTableWithoutNumber`

Comment: @xport-is-sleeping: Your decision. I do not like that. I would use a new letter for another columntype. However, it is possible to overwrite column definitions and it makes no real sense to define a new columntype when you use it only once in the environment, because you can use the definition directly.

Comment: @Herbert, is there `\renewcolumntype` ?

Comment: no, but you can it overwrite it with `\newcolumntype`

Comment: @Herbert, why did you change my original minipage to p in `\newcolumntype`? Is there a something important you considered?

Comment: I will be back 2 hours later.

Answer (score 49):

*always* use `\linewidth` inside the `landscape` environment and *not* `\textwidth`

Comment: For the sake of completeness, could you give me a comment whether or not this calculation `##1\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.5\fboxrule` is correct?

Comment: Please wait for 1 hour, I have a telephone call. I am sorry.

Comment: I edited my code, see above

Answer (score 3):

I found a *very* simple solution:
Just use

```
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{}
%Your table content
\end{tabular}
}
```

Apparently `\linewidth` is redefined by landscape but `\textwidth` not.

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: This solution is intended for **KOMA-script's classes only**.*

---

The `landscape` environment of the `pdflscape` package is indeed the key for creating sideway floats, as shown in [Herbert's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7684/64454). 
Indeed, it rotates the float but keeps head- and footnotes correctly positioned. Moreover, it automatically rotates the relevant page in the pdf, in order to make easy to read the document on screen.

However, as noted in KOMA-Script documentation in §16.6:

> Package `lscape` defines an environment landscape to set the page contents but not head and foot landscape. Inside this environment it changes `\textheight` to the value of `\textwidth`,
>   but it does not change `\textwidth` to the former value of `\textheight`. This is inconsistent.

The solution for KOMA-script's classes is thus to also load the `scrhack` package, *after* `pdflscape`.

[image]

[image]

---

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
    %needed for this solution
    \usepackage{pdflscape}
    \usepackage{scrhack}

    %mainstream packages for tables
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{booktabs}

    %for illustration purpose
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-2]

    \begin{landscape}%
        \captionof{table}[Caption for LoT]{Caption of the table}%
        \small%
        \noindent%
        \begin{tabularx}{\textheight}{lXX}
        \toprule
            \emph{Lorem}
            &
            \textbf{Ipsum dolor}
            &
            \textbf{Sit amet}
        \\
        \midrule
            \emph{Consectetur adipiscing}
            &
            In sed facilisis lacus, consectetur volutpat nulla. Praesent quis vulputate urna.
            &
            Suspendisse non dui fermentum, convallis velit non, consequat diam.
        \\
            \emph{In at sem eros.}
            &
            Maecenas tellus eros, porttitor non varius eget, porttitor eu ipsum.
            &
            Etiam accumsan pharetra convallis. 
        \\
        \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}%
    \end{landscape}

    \lipsum[3-4]
\end{document}
```