# Changing the font size in a table

Tags: tables, floats, fontsize

What's the recommend way of changing the font size in a particular table? Is there a better way than enclosing all values with, for example, the `\tiny` function.

Comment: Please also consider the usage of `\scalebox{}{}` of the `graphicx` package as mentioned here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56035/92521

Answer (score 299, accepted):

Scale down your table to the textwidth

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
  \begin{tabular}{cc}
    Knuth & Lamport
  \end{tabular}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

then you have the optimal font size. However, all tabular lines are also scaled down which doesn't matter because it looks nicer.

Comment: Now if this would only work with text wrapping as well and eliminate the need to manually specify columns widths, that would be awesome.  Is there a way to use your functionality and also have  automatic text wrapping?

Comment: use a `tabularx` with `X` columns

Comment: I  must report that with XeLaTeX it does work, but with LuaLaTeX does not.

Comment: I must add, that the problem is caused by "xetex" option with package "xcolor".

    \usepackage[xetex]{xcolor},

Comment: sure, in that case it works only with a `xetex` driver. However, in general you do not need such an option for `graphicx`

Comment: It was not stated but the caption, `\caption{demo table}`, and label, `\label{tab:demo}`, go outside of the `\resizebox` area.

Comment: I have a table in landscape `\begin{landscape}`. When I used `\textwidth` for defining the width of the resized box, the resulting box had the width of the text of a portrait oriented page. For anybody having the same problem, use`\linewidth` instead of  `\textwidth`, it solved the problem in my case. Source: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7686/118906

Comment: Herbert's answer is very elegant, but it responds strangely with \newpage: - in an environment that goes: [\newpage text table] it outputs in a different order [table text]
- in an environment that goes: [table \newpage text] it doesn't follow the \newpage command

Comment: Inside a table Environment there is already no \newpage possible

Comment: Never use `\resizebox` with tables. If used on multiple tables with different number of columns, it will yield a different font size for each table in the document. It will be ugly.

Comment: It is not only the inconsistency of the font sizes.  This will produce a more obvious inconsistency in the thickness of the table lines.  A  font a bit different of `\small` or `\footnotesize` could go unnoticed at some extent, but lines too thin or too thick attract attention too much, showing  that little effort has been put into the design of the document.

Answer (score 162):

Write `\tiny` immediately after `\begin{table}`. If you don't use a (floating) `table` environment, enclose your (e.g.) `tabular` environment in a group and write `\tiny` after `\begingroup`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\tiny
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}
Knuth & Lamport
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

EDIT: To change the fontsize for *all* tables (or even floats of every type), one may use the [`floatrow`](http://ctan.org/pkg/floatrow) package (this also saves typing `\centering` in every table):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{floatrow}
\DeclareFloatFont{tiny}{\tiny}% "scriptsize" is defined by floatrow, "tiny" not
\floatsetup[table]{font=tiny}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
Knuth & Lamport
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just one quick additional remark: whenever your figure/table has a caption, be sure to change the font size only *after* you've specified the caption. This is particularly important if you're specifying `tiny` or `scriptsize` for the font size.

Comment: Anyway to specify font sizes between \tiny and \small? \tiny is too small for me to read and \small is the same as normal font size

Comment: @sphere How about `\footnotesize`?

Comment: Dredging up the past... @Mico, I don't see this behaviour at all. None of my captions (specified with `\caption`) are affected in any way with a fontsize declaration before them inside a `table` environment.

Answer (score 9):

An easier way to change the font size for ALL tables:

`\usepackage{etoolbox}`

`\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\tiny}`

Comment: Very, _very_ dangerous. A `tabular` may be hidden in places you do not suspect. For example in `\maketitle`.

Comment: I tried but didn't find any differences using `\maketitle`. If it happens, we should set a particular font size for any special tables.

Comment: That was just an example; not every class defines `\maketitle` using a `tabular` but some do (e.g. the standard classes for the author). My point is that there might be a `tabular` hidden somewhere where you do not expect it, and changing the default behaviour of `tabular` might have unforeseeable consequences. So I stand by my opinion that this is dangerous. (I haven't said "bad" or "wrong". Just dangerous.)

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way is using `\fontsize`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\fontsize{9pt}{9pt}\selectfont
  \begin{tabular}{cc}
    Knuth & Lamport
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

More information about the syntax may be found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148508/how-does-fontsize-work).