# Table caption should be left aligned

Tags: horizontal-alignment, floats, captions, indentation

How to make table caption left-aligned.

I tried `\usepackage[singlelinecheck=off]{caption}` but it did not work out. In other words it gives an error:

`\DeclareFloatFont
                      {tiny}{\tiny}% "scriptsize" is defined by floatrow, "t...`

```
    \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage[usenames]{color}
    \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
    \usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
    \usepackage{authblk}

    \usepackage{floatrow}
    \usepackage[labelsep=space]{caption}

    \DeclareFloatFont{tiny}{\tiny}
    \floatsetup[table]{font=footnotesize,capposition=top}

    \linespread{1.6}
    \renewenvironment{abstract}{%
    \noindent\bfseries\abstractname:\normalfont}{}

    \newcommand{\affilmark}[1]{\rlap{\textsuperscript{\itshape#1}}}

    \begin{document}

    \centerline{\LARGE Title}
    \vspace*{3ex}
    \begin{flushleft}\large
    A.B \affilmark{a},\quad
    A.D\affilmark{b}\\[2ex]
    \normalsize\itshape
    \textsuperscript{a}\,University of nowhere,\
    \upshape Corresponding author's email: \texttt{A.D@ieee.org}
    \end{flushleft}
    \date{}

    \begin{abstract}
    abstract goes here
    \end{abstract}


    \section{Introduction}
    some text goes here.

    \begin{figure}[!t]
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth, height=0.2\textwidth]
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]
    \caption{Conventional  (a) ABCD. (b) EFGH.}
    \label{ABCDEFGH}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{table}[!t]

    \caption{performance of .}
    \label{tableII}
    \centering
    \definecolor{latexbl}{RGB}{28,220,240}
    \rowcolors{12}{black}{latexbl}

    \begin{tabular}  {|m{0.8cm}|m{0.6cm}|m{1.35cm}|m{1.1cm}|m{1.5cm}|m{1.1cm}|m{1.4cm}|m{0.7cm}|m{1.75cm}|m{1.2cm}|m{0.5cm}|}
    \hline
    \center Ref. & A &  B& C & D& E& F &G &H&I &J\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{flushleft}
    some explanation
    \end{flushleft}
    \end{table}
    \end{document}
```

EDIT BY LOCKSTEP (moved from separate "answer"):

Here's a compilable example that doesn't show the problematic behaviour mentioned by you. Please use it as start-up aid to post a compilable example which does show the behaviour.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=off]{caption}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}
(Table content)
\caption{A table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a complete [minimal working example](http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html) illustrating the problem.

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina: I edited my question. please read it again.

Comment: It seems you are using code snippets from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27097/changing-the-font-size-in-a-table.

Comment: yes, that's right.

Comment: You have to find out and show us the difference between my compilable example and the things you do (also as a compilable example). I only recognized the code snippet because it was part of another answer of mine.

Comment: @lockstep : this is what I 'm using. please read my post again.

Comment: If I take your new example and add `singlelinecheck=off` to the `caption` package options, the table caption *is* left-aligned.

Comment: wow. but it gives me an error. I add `\usepackage[singlelinecheck=off]{caption}` it at the top of `\DeclareFloatFont{tiny}{\tiny}
\floatsetup[table]{font=footnotesize,capposition=top}` and it gives the following error:`l.13 \DeclareFloatFont
                      {tiny}{\tiny}`

Comment: @amir: If you add `\usepackage[singlelinecheck=off]{caption}` to your preamble you'll try to load the caption package twice but with different options, and this does not work. So try doing what lockstep has suggested instead, which is adding `singlelinecheck=off` to the caption package options.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like you want the captions to have the same width than the width of its figure/table. If this is the case, you can use the `\ffigbox`, and `\ttabbox` commands from the `floatrow` package. A little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage[labelsep=space]{caption}

\DeclareFloatFont{tiny}{\tiny}
\floatsetup[table]{font=footnotesize,capposition=top}

\newcommand\Text{text text text text text text text}% just for the example

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]
{\caption{A figure with its caption having equal width to the figure width}\label{fig:test1}}
{\rule{4cm}{2cm}}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\ttabbox[\FBwidth]
{\caption{A table with its caption having equal width to the table width}\label{fig:test1}}
{\begin{tabular}{p{3cm}p{3cm}}
\Text\Text & \Text\Text \\
\Text\Text & \Text\Text 
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I edit my post (Figure is included). Caption is ok but Figure 1 is displayed below the caption. A line below the caption of figure. Sorry for bad english. `caption of figure` and then below the caption is `Figure 1 C`

Comment: @amir: in the code you just posted there are some errors using the \ffigbox command. Your figure environment should be like this:  `\begin{figure}[!t]
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]%
    {\caption{Conventional  (a) ABCD. (b) EFGH.}\label{ABCDEFGH}}
    {\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth, height=0.2\textwidth]{<name>}}
    \end{figure}` replacing `<name>` with the name of the file containing the image. Correct that part of your example code and report the outcome.

Answer (score 10):

```
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{labelsep=space,justification=justified,singlelinecheck=off}
```

will do what you're asking. There's no error about "tiny".

Comment: Thank you very much bro., egreg. It worked out but all figures and tables are at the center and all captions are left aligned according to text not to border of figures and tables.