# Align table caption to the left of the document

Tags: tables, captions, align

I would like to align the caption of my table to the left of the entire document. I checked for some similar questions but those were asking to align caption to the left of the table.

Here's an MWE. The code for the table was generated automatically via an R package. I'm new to latex and can only suspect that it's something in the table's code. 
Please have a look and help me out!

Thank you.

```
\documentclass[aspaper,12pt,titlepage,oneside]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=40mm,right=25mm,bottom=25mm,top=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter!}
\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
    \caption{Chi-Square Test on Demographics} 
    \label{} 
    \begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}} ccc} 
        \\[-1.8ex]\hline 
        \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
        variable & stat & pValue \\ 
        \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
        Gender & $0$ & $1$ \\ 
        Level of Education & $5.658$ & $0.129$ \\ 
        Forecast Expertise & $0$ & $1$ \\ 
        Forecast Education Type & $1.380$ & $0.710$ \\ 
        Use of Calculator & $0.573$ & $0.449$ \\ 
        \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
    \end{tabular} 
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Of course, there's no value in using `\label{}`, nor does `report` have an `aspaper` size (should probably be `a4paper`); just so you know...

Comment: If think [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28386/141947) is what you need

Comment: Thanks for your heads-up Werner. Do you happen to have a solution to my problem? I have other tables that have some value inside \label{} and their captions also don't align to the left of the document.

Comment: If you want the caption on the left SIDE, then check out the `sidecap` package: http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/sidecap/sidecap.pdf

Comment: Hi BambOo, thank you! The solution you pointed out worked!

Comment: @Michelle, no problem, you're welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the `caption` package and the following `\captionsetup` code

```
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{skip=0pt,singlelinecheck=off}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Myles, thank you. This worked! I assume this modifies the setup specifically for table captions? So, if I want captions for figure to behave differently it won't interfere right?

Comment: Yes, to modify figure captions use `\captionsetup[figure]`.

Comment: What worked for me in the end was `\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption}` and `\captionsetup{skip=0pt,justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=off}` thanks to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/435579/14527). I may have something unnecessary from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136689/14527), but now that things are working I'm moving on with the project!