# Left align caption of table

Tags: tables, captions

I try to left align the caption to my table. When I use the according code it is indeed left-aligned but is more left than the table. How could I fix this?

Thanks a lot,

Julia

this is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc,caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
  \captionsetup{labelfont=bf,
              justification=raggedright,
              singlelinecheck=false}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]

  \centering

  \caption{Percentage of Missing Values in the Analysis Variables}
\begin{tabular}{lS}
\textbf{Variable} & {Percent missing}\\
\toprule
\textbf{x} & 9.37 \\
\textbf{Lxon} & 0.94 \\
\textbf{x} & 0 \\
\textbf{x} & 0.04 \\
\textbf{x} & 0.34 \\
\textbf{Exl} & 7.93 \\
\textbf{Rxe} & 15.32 \\
\textbf{Sxm} & 8.69 \\
\textbf{Txal} & 4.43 \\
\textbf{x} & 1.33 \\
\textbf{Nxnces} & 0.9 \\
\textbf{xs} & 1.12 \\
\textbf{Fxans} & 0 \\
\textbf{xxation} & 2.4 \\
\textbf{Cxon} & 0.58 \\
\textbf{xg} & 0 \\
\textbf{x x} & 0.22 \\
\textbf{x to x from x o. x} & 1.03 \\
\textbf{x to x} & 0.76 \\
\textbf{x} & 0.99 \\
\textbf{x} & 0.09 \\
\textbf{x} & 0.83 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want the caption to have the same width as the table? Edit: or does removing `singlelinecheck=false` to what you want?

Comment: See this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3176/how-can-i-left-align-a-caption

Comment: Removing it does solve my problem, thanks a lot!

Comment: Ah no unfortunately it does not. I want it to start at the same point as my table

Comment: And the table should be centered? Should the caption be constrained to the width of the table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Citing from the [threeparttable](http://ctan.asis.io/macros/latex/contrib/threeparttable/threeparttable.pdf) package:

> This package facilitates tables with titles (captions) and notes. The title and
>   notes are given a width equal to the body of the table (a `tabular` environment).
>   By itself, a `threeparttable` does not float, but you can put it in a `table` or
>   a `table*` or some other floating environment. (This causes extra typing, but
>   gives more flexibility.)

So, `threeparttable` package directly addresses your problem. There are other options like `\parbox` or setting `\captionsetup{width=..}`, but are less flexible.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption,threeparttable}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\captionsetup{labelfont=bf,
              justification=raggedright,
              singlelinecheck=false}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}      % <===
\caption{Percentage of Missing Values in the Analysis Variables}
\begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries}lS}
    Variable           & {Percent missing} \\ \toprule
    x                  & 9.37              \\
    Lxon               & 0.94              \\
    x                  & 0                 \\
    x                  & 0.04              \\
    x                  & 0.34              \\
    Exl                & 7.93              \\
    Rxe                & 15.32             \\
    Sxm                & 8.69              \\
    Txal               & 4.43              \\
    x                  & 1.33              \\
    Nxnces             & 0.9               \\
    xs                 & 1.12              \\
    Fxans              & 0                 \\
    xxation            & 2.4               \\
    Cxon               & 0.58              \\
    xg                 & 0                 \\
    x x                & 0.22              \\
    x to x from x o. x & 1.03              \\
    x to x             & 0.76              \\
    x                  & 0.99              \\
    x                  & 0.09              \\
    x                  & 0.83              \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
\end{threeparttable}         % <===
\label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: What worked for me in the end was `\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption}` and `\captionsetup{skip=0pt,justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=off}`. I may have something unnecessary from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136689/14527) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/427445/14527), but now that things are working I'm moving on with the project!