# Different sizes of font available in table?

Tags: fontsize

I have a table and it appears I only have two options when it comes to font size:  large and small.  There should be a medium option, correct?  I get an error when I replace small or large with medium.

The beginning of my table looks like this:

```
\begin{table*}[ht]
{\small
\hfill{}
\small
\begin{tabular}{|p{3.5cm}|p{8cm}|p{5cm}|}
```

How do I get a universal font size for the table that is not huge or too small to read?

Answer (score 194, accepted):

There's no `\medium` font size between `\small` and `\large`; you have `\normalsize` (which is the default font size). The standard font size switches are: `\tiny`, `\scriptsize`, `\footnotesize`, `\small`, `\normalsize`, `\large`, `\Large`, `\LARGE`, `\huge`, and `\Huge`.

By the way, you only need one font switch command inside the `table` and braces are not required since `table` forms a group, so you can simply say something like this:

```
\begin{table}
\small
\begin{tabular}{p{3.5cm}p{8cm}p{5cm}}
text & text & text
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: @sphere: yes: `\scriptsize`, and `\footnotesize`. Also, for even finer control, as long as the current font supports the desired size, you can use `\fontsize{<size>}{<baseline>}\selectfont` (in a group); as in `{\fontsize{6}{7.2}\selectfont text here}`.

Comment: Can I put that wrapper around an entire table?

Comment: @sphere environments create a group, so inside a `table` *environment* you can say, for example `\begin{table}\fontsize{6}{7.2}\selectfont...\end{table}`.

Comment: I tried your last comment and only some of my text got resized.

Comment: Edit: I got the text resized by copy and pasting the command in more locations, but now the horizontal bars hit the text. Any ideas? Do I need to make blank lines now?

Comment: @sphere you need to provide the actual code you are using. Feel free to open a new question.

Answer (score 7):

If you need to fine tune the size of a table, you can include it in a `scalebox`from the [graphicx](https://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx)- or [graphics-package](https://ctan.org/pkg/graphics) and scale the table to fit. If you need more options, you can use the [adjustbox-package](https://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox).

*A warning*: Arbitrary adjustments of different tables will result in different font sizes. This may look ugly.