# Most minimally invasive changes to get columns vertically centered

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, multirow

I will never forgive TeX for making vertically centering tables so difficult.

I have been trying for years (actually, yes, years) to properly format tables like the following. This is my last attempt before submitting. I am already mentally prepared to submit ugly tables.

Does anyone have a **minimally invasive** trick to get the first column to be properly vertically centered? What is causing the issues?

The current table looks like an absolute train wreck (red rectangle highlights the messed up column).

[image: How it looks currently]

The TeX code that is responsible for the mess:

```
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

% add spacing for table
{\def\arraystretch{1.3}\tabcolsep=10pt

% Table based on Springer template
\begin{table}[ht]
\footnotesize % small font size (source: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56008/different-sizes-of-font-available-in-table)
% table caption is above the table
\caption[Mitigation situations]{Mitigation situations}
\label{tab:mititgation_phase}       % Give a unique label
% For LaTeX tables use
\begin{tabular}{m{3cm}m{11cm}} %
\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
\textbf{} & \textbf{Vulnerability of an existing or planned future supply chain}\\
\noalign{\smallskip}\hline\noalign{\smallskip}

\multirow{4}{3cm}{\textbf{Various forms of supplier concentration}}
    
    & Dependencies on a single shared supplier on a sub-tier level  \\

    & Geographical concentration of sub-tier suppliers  \\
    
    & Undesirable levels of suppliers depending on specific countries or other political unions (relevant in cases of tariffs etc.) \\
    
    & Limited number of available alternative suppliers or trends towards such a market consolidation \\
    
\hline

\multirow{2}{3cm}{\textbf{Various forms of undesirable supply chain participants}}
    
    & Dependencies on previously unknown, undesirable sub-tier suppliers (legal risks, quality risks, availability risks, blacklisted by authorities, unsustainable, unethical etc.)  \\

    & Dependencies on individual sub-tier suppliers located in high-risk areas (e.g. prone to natural disasters) \\
    
\hline

\multirow{3}{3cm}{\textbf{Various forms of overlapping, competing or otherwise interfering supply chains}}
    
    & Seemingly unrelated industries competing for the same resources as the OEM and potentially negatively impacting supply  \\

    & Dependencies on the health of a supply chain that produces complementary parts (see the case study in Section~\ref{sec:2011_thailand_floods} where demand for Intel's chips was impacted by an HDD shortage) \\
    
    & Competitors and otherwise risky (e.g. financially unstable) businesses using (and potentially negatively impacting) identical supply chain participants \\

\hline

\textbf{Dependencies on problematic parts or materials} & E.g. dependencies on parts or materials on a sub-tier level with uncertain supply (e.g. rare earth elements that are mostly mined in China) \\

\noalign{\smallskip}\hline

\end{tabular}
\end{table}

} % closing bracket for extra spacing for table
```

Comment: it would look better with top ligned but you are not specifying vertical centering anywhere, or at least you are but then over-riding it with multirow.

Comment: please always post the code in a form that people can run it to see the issue,

Comment: @DavidCarlisle How could I minimally invasively vertically center-align the first column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have loaded `booktabs`, but are not using it, and are using `array` but not loaded it, and use of `multirow` is preventing the vertical alignment.

You can simplify the markup greatly:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\addtolength\textwidth{80pt}% since you specified the table width and it doesn't fit otherwise

\usepackage{booktabs,array}
\begin{document}

% Table based on Springer template
\begin{table}[htp] % you almost always want p
\footnotesize % small font size (source: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56008/different-sizes-of-font-available-in-table)
% table caption is above the table
\caption[Mitigation situations]{Mitigation situations}
\label{tab:mititgation_phase}       % Give a unique label

\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright}m{3cm}>{\parskip=.5\baselineskip}m{11cm}} %
 & \textbf{Vulnerability of an existing or planned future supply chain}\\

\toprule

\textbf{Various forms of supplier concentration}
&    
     Dependencies on a single shared supplier on a sub-tier level 

     Geographical concentration of sub-tier suppliers 
    
    Undesirable levels of suppliers depending on specific countries or other political unions (relevant in cases of tariffs etc.)
    
    Limited number of available alternative suppliers or trends towards such a market consolidation
\\
\midrule

\textbf{Various forms of undesirable supply chain participants}
&
    
    Dependencies on previously unknown, undesirable sub-tier suppliers (legal risks, quality risks, availability risks, blacklisted by authorities, unsustainable, unethical etc.)

    Dependencies on individual sub-tier suppliers located in high-risk areas (e.g. prone to natural disasters)
\\
\midrule

\textbf{Various forms of overlapping, competing or otherwise interfering supply chains}
&
     Seemingly unrelated industries competing for the same resources as the OEM and potentially negatively impacting supply

     Dependencies on the health of a supply chain that produces complementary parts (see the case study in Section~\ref{sec:2011_thailand_floods} where demand for Intel's chips was impacted by an HDD shortage)
    
  Competitors and otherwise risky (e.g. financially unstable) businesses using (and potentially negatively impacting) identical supply chain participants
\\
\midrule

\textbf{Dependencies on problematic parts or materials}
&E.g. dependencies on parts or materials on a sub-tier level with uncertain supply (e.g. rare earth elements that are mostly mined in China)
\\
\bottomrule

\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much!

Comment: @pascal next time please post a document (as here) not fragments with missing packages:-)

Comment: Will do. I did not do it on purpose. It was purely my incompetence in understanding which packages are actually used / loaded.

Comment: @pascal that's why it is better to post an actual document, then you don't need to guess which packages are needed, you can test the document shows the problem before posting