# How does \fontsize{}{} work?

Tags: fontsize

With the package `anyfontsize` I can use the command `\fontsize{}{}`. But the second argument seems to be without any effect. I read [there](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Fonts) that it is related to the line space. It doesn't work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\begin{document}

{\fontsize{1cm}{1cm}\selectfont First test : I need to put some text here.}

\bigskip

{\fontsize{1cm}{2cm}\selectfont Second test : I need to put some text here --- does it work?}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Any clue?**

Comment: Note that loading `fontspec` for Xelatex of Lualatex, you do not need to explicitly load `anyfontsize`.

Comment: This is just an instance of the more general problem in this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/354669/1340

Comment: Same cause as [paragraphs - Temporarily increase line spacing - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48741/temporarily-increase-line-spacing/48743#48743)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You need to end the paragraph before you close the group. While the fontsize is updated when you issue `\selectfont` the new leading only is updated when the paragraph is ended.  In your case the group ends (with `}`) *before* the paragraph ends (the empty line after the line end).  Either write

```
{\fontsize{1cm}{2cm}\selectfont Second test : I need to put some text here ---
  does it work?

}
```

or use `\par` at the end:

```
{\fontsize{1cm}{2cm}\selectfont Second test : I need to put some text here ---
  does it work?\par}
```

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\begin{document}

{\fontsize{1cm}{1cm}\selectfont First test : I need to put some text here.\par}

\bigskip

{\fontsize{1cm}{2cm}\selectfont Second test : I need to put some text here ---
  does it work?\par}

\end{document}
```

[image]