# Impact of enclosing lines with curly brackets

Tags: spacing, brackets, braces

When I compile the following (almost identical) two pieces of code, there is much more vertical space between both words in the first example than in the second example:

```
% Much space between the hellos
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\Huge Hello

{\Huge Hello}
\end{document}
```

and

```
% Almost no space between the hellos
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
{\Huge Hello}

{\Huge Hello}
\end{document}
```

What is the reason for that? What difference do the curly brackets make at this point?

Comment: `{\Huge Hello\par}`

Comment: The is a very common mistake; you need to issue an explicit `\par` so that the paragraph algorithm can take into account the new `\baselineskip`, or leave an empty line (an implicit `\par`).

Comment: in the second baselineskip=12pt (normal) in the first 30pt (Huge)

Comment: Okay, and what exactly are the situtations which require an explicit `\par`? Every time the last character of a paragraph is a curly bracket?

Comment: In the first case the baselineskip is Huge in the second it is normalsize (whatever the exact values are). See here for a similar question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/148508/