# How does \fontsize{}{} work internally?

Tags: fonts

I found this question [How does \fontsize{}{} work?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148508/how-does-fontsize-work) while looking for an understanding of `\selectfont`, but I was disappointed to see that the term "work" was referring to its usage and not to its implementation i.e. how it actually works internally.

Where is `\fontsize{}{}\selectfont` documented? Is it wrong to think it should be included in source2e? If so, why?

Comment: `\fontsize` and `\set@fontsize` is documented in source2e.pdf. Didn't you found it?

Comment: No. I will use my eyes next time. I am not sure whether I should close this question in shame or leave it open for the next nincompoop.

Comment: For code of `\selectfont` see `latex.ltx` around line 2708.

Comment: There are other nincompoops (e.g., me) here who might find it useful, haha.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the code:

```
2400 \DeclareRobustCommand\fontsize[2]
2401    {\set@fontsize\baselinestretch{#1}{#2}}

2697 \def\set@fontsize#1#2#3{%
2698     \@defaultunits\@tempdimb#2pt\relax\@nnil
2699     \edef\f@size{\strip@pt\@tempdimb}%
2700     \@defaultunits\@tempskipa#3pt\relax\@nnil
2701     \edef\f@baselineskip{\the\@tempskipa}%
2702     \edef\f@linespread{#1}%
2703     \let\baselinestretch\f@linespread
2704       \def\size@update{%
2705         \baselineskip\f@baselineskip\relax
2706         \baselineskip\f@linespread\baselineskip
2707         \normalbaselineskip\baselineskip
2708         \setbox\strutbox\hbox{%
2709           \vrule\@height.7\baselineskip
2710                 \@depth.3\baselineskip
2711                 \@width\z@}%
2712         \let\size@update\relax}%
2713   }
```

1. `\@defaultunits` is responsible for adding `pt` to the argument if just a number appears, storing the value in either `\@tempdimb` (for the size argument) or in `\@tempskipa` (for the baseline skip argument)
2. `\f@size` and `\f@baselineskip` are set to the value in points (no unit) from the two arguments to `\fontsize`
3. `\f@linespread` is set from the first argument, that is, from `\baselinestretch`
4. A temporary macro is defined for updating the values, which will be executed at the next `\selectfont` command; the macro \size@update`will then redefine itself to be`\relax`

Note that `\size@update` will also contain a redefinition of the `\strutbox`, so a `\strut` will always be fit to the current font size.

You can call `\fontsize{3cm}{4cm}` or `\fontsize{15}{18}` or any mixture with or without units; a unitless is implicitly assumed to be in points.