# can I change the font in the definition?

Tags: fonts

I'm using the font family mathptmx and I want to use baskervald only for the alphabet Q (not always but in many specific situation). So I defined

```
\def\Q{{\fontfamily{ybv}\selectfont
Q}}
```

But this does not work. How should I modify this?

Comment: E.g. `\def\Q{{\fontfamily{ybv}\fontsize{1cm}{2cm}\selectfont
Q}}`, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/153659. It is general not recommended to use a single-letter macro like `\Q`, nor to use `\def` to define them (rather you should use `\newcommand`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I try this code

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathptmx}

\def\Q{{\fontfamily{ybv}\selectfont Q}}

\begin{document}

Q\Q

\end{document}
```

I get the following warning on the console

```latex
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/ybv/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `OT1/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 8.
```

It means that Baskervald is not available in the default OT1 encoding.

Changing this to

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\def\Q{{\fontfamily{ybv}\selectfont Q}}

\begin{document}

Q\Q

\end{document}
```

might seem to solve the issue. However, you should be aware of two problems:

1. `mathptmx` has been created a couple of decades ago as a way to get not too heavy PostScript output from LaTeX documents;
2. `\def` is quite a dangerous command for being used by a beginner (or even an advanced user).

Issue 1 is solved by using a properly designed Times-like typeface with accompanying math font; issue 2 is solved by `\newcommand`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\newcommand\Q{{\fontfamily{ybv}\selectfont Q}}

\begin{document}

Q\Q

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! This completely solves my problem. By the way, could you explain a bit more why \def is dangerous? Is \newcommand better than \def in most of the situation?

Comment: @HLEE You can easily see the problem if you do `\def\box#1{\framebox[2\width]{#1}}` (silly definition, just to make you see the issue) and use `\box{ABC}` in the document. With `\newcommand` you don't risk to redefine a command you don't know about.