# Adjust line height locally

Tags: formatting, line-spacing, parts

I was trying to create a custom 'part', So, to do that I have written the following code,

```
\newcommand\partino[2]
{\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{{#2}}\thispagestyle{empty}
    {\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
        \rule{0pt}{0.05\textheight}
        
        {\LARGE \bfseries\scshape {Part \:\:#1}}
        
        \vspace{1.5em}
        {\huge \bfseries\scshape{#2}}
        
        \vspace{2.5cm}  
}}
```

The resulting part is as follows,

[image]

Note that the line height is unnatural, how do I fix this?

Comment: You need to place a `\par` after the parts of your code that you want to print `\LARGE` or `\huge` in order to get the line spacing right.

Comment: @JasperHabicht What do you mean?

Comment: Try `{\LARGE \bfseries\scshape {Part \:\:#1}\par}` and `{\huge \bfseries\scshape{#2}\par}`.

Comment: Ok cool, it worked, I put \par outside the braces and that didn't work

Comment: Essentially, it is the same problem as this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/148508/47927 . (You don't use `\fontsize`, but `\Large` and `\huge` do quite the same.)

Comment: @JasperHabicht Thanks sir!