# Something in between \Large and \LARGE

Tags: fontsize

Is it possible to compile some text with a size in between `\Large` and `\LARGE`? I would like to fine-tune the size of some title without affecting the rest of the document.

**Edit:** I didn't know the command `\fontsize{}{}` before, learning how to correctly use the command solved the problem. [For me this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/153659/193813) solved the problem, not the linked question.

Comment: @user202729 Thank you for the comment. Do you know by any chance whether the proposed solutions affect the entire document (this would be a no-go for me)?

Comment: Like all fontsize changes, if you put it inside a group, it will stay inside the group.  Groups include environments, {...}, \bgroup ... \egroup, \hbox{...}, etc.

Comment: The `fontsize` package provides the intermediate commands `\Larger`, `\Largerr`, `\Largerrr`. Similarly for the other commands: `\large`, `\huge`, etc.